# xcode 12.1 any image from assets returns nil in run time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

after updating xcode to 12 and cocoapods to 1.10.0
i tried to make pod install then i ran the project
any image i try to read from Assets.xcassets returned nil, only images from my pods are working fine
here's the podfile

```
 platform :ios, '12.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

target 'SignifyClients' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SignifyClients
    pod 'iOSFoundation', :git => 'https://dcywelllyerxjadgx45xcxtdcpd7d7f2kq3n7456byr3i6jt34sa@dev.azure.com/Smaat-Signify/Lavad/_git/iOS-Foundation', :branch => 'develop'
#    pod 'iOSFoundation', :path => '../iOS-Foundation’

    pod 'RangeSeekSlider'
    pod 'AppCenter'
    pod 'Frames'
    pod 'ReadMoreTextView'
    pod 'CropViewController'
    pod 'GooglePlaces'
    pod 'Hero'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    pod 'StepIndicator'
  target 'SignifyClientsTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I've been through this issue for 2 days please advise

Comment: How are you getting the images? `UIImage(named: "yourImageName")`?

Comment: Yes the default way @aheze